# How can I change a network password that Windows Explorer has saved?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-explorer

I use Windows 7 and I saved my login to a server in the network. But meanwhile my password has changed. When I now try to access that server then Windows Explorer automatically uses the old user and password, so I get an "Access denied" popup. And my account is blocked after 3 failed login attempts.

How can I delete or change the saved password?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Windows 7 has a [Credential Manager](http://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-delete-saved-passwords-for-network-drives-in-windows/) which lets you view/modify that information.
To access it press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, input `control keymgr.dll`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Alternately, you can find the tool under Control Panel > Network and Internet > User Accounts > Credential Manager.

Comment: Credentials for Outlook on Windows 7 are also located in the Credential Manager - for example, I found a credential for publishing my Outlook Calendar to CalDAV server in there, and this enabled me to change the password.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (using Windows 7). I use Windows Explorer (sometimes) to upload new files to my web servers but I do not ever use IE (Internet Explorer). I wasn't coming up with any valid solutions on this topic so I tried some things of my own. Long story, short: go into Internet Explorer and clear the history including passwords. Since I don't use IE, I cleared everything... cache, cookies, passwords, etc. Clearing out IE cleared out Windows Explorer and I was able to input new usernames and passwords.