# How to disconnect from shared computer when logged in through Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, logout

Every time I need to access a remote computer through Windows Explorer I need to log in and that's fine.

Once I enter the log in credentials I can access all shared folders to the remote computer.
The remote computer is in the same network.

The problem is that I do not know how to log out. I need to be able to disconnect from the remote computer. I need Windows Explorer to ask me for log in credentials again.

I tried to use net use command like:

net use \patrik-hp\IPC$ /delete where the remote computer is patrik-hp.

This works on Windows XP but doesn't work on Windows 7.
Does anybody has an idea why?  What I need to do to achieve this.

On Windows XP when you delete the connection through net use the windows explorer asks for the password when trying to access the remote computer.

On Windows 7 is different. Windows Explorer keeps the password.
Windows credential manager does not show any stored passwords.

Stopping Workstation and/or Server windows services does not help.
Stopping Workstation only temporary blocks the access to the remote computer but Windows Explorer starts it again and the connection is there again.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command prompt as administrator and run:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

There you can edit and/or remove stored connection settings. You can even back them up before changing anything.

Comment: Just found (under "Related" to this question, nonetheless) a nicer user interface for the same function: enter `control keymgr.dll` in a command prompt ( from [link](http://superuser.com/questions/70030/how-can-i-change-a-network-password-that-windows-explorer-has-saved?rq=1) )